# Get number of keys on a keyboard using python

Tags: python, keyboard

How to get the number of keys on my keyboard on Linux using python or how can I get list of all available keys?

Comment: Do you mean actual physical keys? Does a power key count, the fn toggle key? Or are you talking about possible inputs you can receive from the keyboard?

Comment: I mean actual physical keys